# How do I check the value of PrintDialog.AllowCurrentPage?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have a printdialog that I do the following with:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.AllowCurrentPage = true;
pd.UseEXDialog = true;
if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
```

Once the user has hit OK, I need to see if the "Current Page" or the "All pages" button is highlighted so I can ... gosh ... print All pages or just the current page.

However, I have *no clue* where the corresponding property for .AllowCurrentPage is. It should be in the intellisense, but at the very least, in the documentation, which it isn't. (In fact, the documentation for PrintDialog notes that my above code should throw an exception for not setting .PrintSettings, which it doesn't.) Subsequent Googling turned up nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. It's hidden here:

```
PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange
```

It's an enum, so intellisense didn't prompt me with anything useful on my first pass. It would be really, *really* nice if this were documented on .AllowCurrentPage.

Comment: Nice I spent hours on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The enumeration of this is at `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintRange`

Possibilities are:

- .AllPages
- .CurrentPage
- .Selection
- .SomePages

Found this when I was trying to figure out which RadioButton was selected.
I wanted the current page, so I had to do:

```
Boolean curPage = (printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == System.Drawing.Printing.PrintRange.CurrentPage);
```

Not very intuitive the way they have it set up.